# Remove Warnings from Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

Directory not found for option '-F/Users/amimodi/Downloads/VW'
 Directory not found for option '-F/Users/amimodi/Desktop/VW'

how to remove this warning coming in Xcode project ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If it is a "directory not found for option '-F/..."** That means it's a Framework Error, and you should try this:

1.Click on your project (targets)

2.Click on Build Settings

3.Under Framework Search Paths, delete the paths which cause warning's

It might happens when you move referenced file around